# How to show roles in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, membership-provider

I am getting user list using `Membership.GetAllUsers()` function. And I bind this data in a grid view.

But I cannot find the roles information here. I need to show the roles in that grid view.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser(user)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx

**UPDATE**

This is going to be pretty slow if you have a lot of users

```
GridView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView_RowDataBound);

void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    GridView gridview = (GridView)sender;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        string username = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "yourusernamecolumn").ToString();
        Literal c = new Literal();
        c.Text = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username).ToString(); //decide how you want to display the list
        e.Row.Cells[somecolumnindex].Controls.Add(c);
    }
}
```

It might be better to read straight from your role-to-member table.

Comment: But how I combined the role information with the user's other information and bind them in my datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

[Use RoleProvider.GetAllRoles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getallroles.aspx).